# Mine Composer Autoload PSR-4 is not working

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4, psr-0

I have a problem with my composer and I don't know where to run. I took several classes on how to do this, but my composer doesn't work well. It manages to import my database connection class, but the rest of the classes, in other files, cannot.

My composer.json it is like this:

```
{
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
      "Src\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

The namespace in the file looks like this:

```
namespace Src\Model;
```

And the instance happens this way:

```
$instance = new \Src\Model\CrudUsuario();
```

The error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Src\Model\CrudUsuario' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Src\Controller\crud_usuario.php on line 79

Comment: Hello, what is you directory architecture. Does you have the file `src/Model/CrudUsuario` ?

Comment: The path to the file is: www -> Src -> Model -> crud_usuario.php

Comment: OOOWW thanks bro, the name of my file needs to be CrudUsuario. which is strange, because for me the reference Src\Model\CrudUsuario should be for the class